# setFetchSize Mariadb jdbcdriver version 3.0.4

Tags: jdbc, mariadb

We encounter an error when we go from 2.7.2 et 3.0.4 MariaDB JDBC driver with setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=27489500) invalid fetch size

So we switch to `setFetchSize(1)`

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/

> Before version 1.4.0, the only accepted value for fetch size was
> Statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE) (equivalent to
> Statement.setFetchSize(1)). This value is still accepted for
> compatilibity reasons but rather use Statement.setFetchSize(1), since
> according to JDBC the value must be >= 0.

And I found nothing in the release notes.

Answer (score 7):

here is how I solved it:

you have to lower the version of MariaDB. you go to the driver list, select Maria DB, click on + and add something lower; 2.7.3 worked for me. What is very very important is that you click on **"create data source"** that will led you to create another connect. I did not work without creating a new data source with lower version for me.

[image]

Comment: This led me the solution for my case. I noticed MySQL version wasn't upgraded. It started working after upgrading to the stable version.

Answer (score 6):

This is a connector or idea bug, you need to downgrade.

I have the same problem, on the datagrid, searching the forums, the recommended solution is to reduce the version until the fix is released.

Ref: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16376

Answer (score 0):

DB:mariadb 10.4, IDE phpstorm 2021.1.1

My error is: (conn=9) invalid fetch size.
and 11 duplicate reports (1 sec, 723 ms)

My decision is: create data source not mariadb but mysql(will tell you that need select mariadb, don't worry, connect), and all work